# Automatic Email reply

Tags: php, email

Im wanting to send an automatic email to a customer that has filled out my contact form. When the form is filled out it send the values of the form to me but wont send an email back to the contact. this is what i have so far.

```
$name = $_POST["fullname"];
$email = $_POST["emailaddress"];
$comments = $_POST["comment"];
$gender = $_POST["gender"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$Interested = $_POST['Interested'];
$heard = $_POST["Heard"];


$message = "New Email from a customer" .



         "\r\nName of the contact" .
         "\r\n-". $name .
         "\r\nEmail address of the contact" . 
         "\r\n-".$email .
         "\r\nThe comment that the contact has made" . 
         "\r\n-".$comments .
         "\r\nThe gender of the contact" . 
         "\r\n-".$gender .
         "\r\nThe age range of the contact" . 
         "\r\n-".$age .
         "\r\nThe products that the customer is interested in" . 
         "\r\n-".implode(", " ,$Interested).
         "\r\nWhere the contact heard of us"  .
         "\r\n-".$Heard.
 $headers =  "From: " . $email;
 "Reply-To: \r\n" . $email . " Thank you for your message";

mail("me@localhost",$subject,$message,$headers);

?>
```

Comment: I don't see you trying to send a second email.

Comment: So just add a 2nd mail() sending it to the customer... ?

Comment: Side note: your `$headers` is completely wrong.

Comment: Thanks Tularis got it sorted now. It was what you said.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider Why are they wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add that on the end of your code :

```
$subjectReply = 'Thank you for your contact..';
$messageReply = 'You will soon receive an answer';
$headers = 'From: me@localhost';

mail($email, $subjectReply, $messageReply, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is send a second email back to the person filling out the contact form:

```
$message = "Thanks for getting in touch. We'll be in contact with you soon";
$reply_headers =  "From: me@localhost;";

mail( $email, "Thank you for contacting us", $reply_message, $reply_headers );
```

The reply-to header you're trying to set is not the automated reply one. It's the email address that replies to the email go to.